# Can I use the OR operator within the contains() function in xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have an xpath statement that I want to lead to the text after a field that is either titled `Author:` or `Authors:`, depending on the specific web page that it is leading to. Right now, my xpath to that node looks like this:

`//strong[contains(.,'Author:')]/following-sibling::text()`

When this xpath statement is applied to a page that has `Authors:` instead of `Author`, however, it does not read the text that comes after the `<strong>` tag. I've tried making the xpath statement read

`//strong[contains(.,'Author:') OR contains(.,'Authors:')]/following-sibling::text()`,

but I get a formula parse error.

Am I using the OR operator incorrectly? Is there another way for the xpath statement to read the text after either the `Author:` or the `Authors:` text, whichever one it might be? (There are never both on the same page.)

Thanks!

Comment: Remember: XPath is **case-sensitive**. So change the operator to `or` instead of  `OR` and your expression will be fine.

Comment: @zx485 That did the trick! Thank you so much!